# Win2016 DNS Manager nslookup returns Default Server: Unknown

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2016, nslookup

I have a Windows 2016 server running as a Tertiary Domain Controller and the issue I'm seeing is that when I run nslookup from the DNS manager it returns 'Default Server: Unknown' with the correct local IP Address.  It should return the fqdn of the host server. This dns server was installed as part of Domain Controller install.
If I open up a separate cmd prompt and type nslookup it returns 'Default Server:   which is fine and the local server IP address, which is also what I expect.

My question is: why can't nslookup in DNS manager find the fqdn of the local server?

Answer (score 0):

When you launch nslookup from DNS Manager, nslookup connects to the DNS server using the first ip address bound to the DNS server (as seen on the Advanced tab of the DNS server properties), which is the IPv6 address.

When you launch nslookup from the command prompt it connects to the DNS server using the IPv4 address configured as the primary DNS server in the DNS client settings of the server NIC.

If you don't have an IPv6 rDNS zone that includes an IPv6 PTR record for the server then that would be the expected behavior when launching nslookup from DNS Manager. Nslookup can't resolve the host name of the server from the IPv6 address because no IPv6 rDNS zone and PTR record exists, and so nslookup reports "Default Server: Unknown".

Because you do have an IPv4 rDNS zone that includes an IPv4 PTR record for the server (as evidenced by the output of nslookup launched from the command prompt), nslookup is able to resolve the host name of the server from the IPv4 PTR record when you launch nslookup from the command prompt.

What you're seeing is the expected behavior.